# Why do I get "type annotations needed" when using the nightly implementation of try blocks?

Tags: rust

I was playing around with [`try` blocks](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/unstable-book/language-features/try-blocks.html) but I can't figure out how to make this code work ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=db9ae1deebb8270a814534a6e4a2d6c2)):

```
#![feature(try_blocks)]

fn get_val(vec: Vec<i32>) -> Result<i32, String> {
    let (v1, v2) =
        try { (vec.get(0)?, vec.get(1)?) }.ok_or("failed to collect elements".to_string())?;

    if v1 < v2 {
        return Err("condition failed".to_string());
    }
    Ok(v1 + v2)
}
```

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/lib.rs:5:9
  |
5 |         try { (vec.get(0)?, vec.get(1)?) }.ok_or("failed to collect elements".to_string())?;
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
  |
  = note: type must be known at this point
```

Comment: See also [How do I fix the error “type annotations needed” when creating a closure that uses the try operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51476828/155423)

Comment: It's hard to answer multiple questions made in one post, so I've removed the unrelated question. Please separate them into multiple questions so that we can help you better and so that your questions will help others in the future that have one of the same questions as you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust can't infer the type of your try block. Your sample code looks like

```
let (v1, v2) =
    try { (vec.get(0)?, vec.get(1)?) }.ok_or("failed to collect elements".to_string())?;
```

In Rust, `?` (and by extension the `try { ... }` nightly feature) can return a value of any type which implements the [`Try`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Try.html) trait. Now, it's obvious to a *human* reader that you want `Option<(&i32, &i32)>`, but to the computer, you could also want some other type. Specifically, any type which implements `Try` and has an `ok_or` method would suffice.

You can make the code work with an explicit type signature

```
let tmp: Option<(&i32, &i32)> = try { (vec.get(0)?, vec.get(1)?) };
let (v1, v2) =
    tmp.ok_or("failed to collect elements".to_string())?;
```